# List items using nested for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm newbie to coding and this makes me crazy. I'm trying to compare items of a list to eliminate the duplicates but it doesn't work.
here results are fine:

```
L = [1, 2, 3]
for i in L[:]:
    for j in L[:]:
        print(L.index(i), i, L.index(j), j)
```

but if I change the list to this:

```
    L = [1, 1, 3]
```

it won't work. it skips some items and prints some others twice. any ideas?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? not sure I understand. Maybe you want to loop over indices instead of elements here?

Comment: `index` only returns the _first_ index for a particular value

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What is your end goal? There's likely a better solution, perhaps using `set`s.

Comment: I just want to use a loop to compare all items in list,that's all. I know there might be tons of solutions to my problem but I want to try it this way.just a simple question?How to use nested loop to compare all items of a list 2 by 2?

Answer (score 2):

You can change it to `set` which ensures items are unique:

```
In [1]: my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

In [2]: my_new_list = list(set(my_list))

In [3]: my_new_list
Out[3]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Keep in mind, however, that `set` is unorderd data structure, which means the order may differ.

In you case you can check it this way:

```
In [4]: my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

In [5]: my_new_list = []

In [6]: for element in my_list:
   ...:     if element not in my_new_list:
   ...:         my_new_list.append(element)
   ...:         

In [7]: my_new_list
Out[7]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

Comment: What if he wants to keep repeated items?

Comment: What do you mean? The problem is with removing duplicates.

Comment: @A.B. Docs say it's immutable but not that it maintains any specific order. If you can prove it is other way I'll be happy to update answer and learn something new.

Comment: Thanks for your help.It helped a lot. but actually I was going to practice loops and kind of solve the problem by my own way.not by using some other functions. for example I know there is a "max"  built in function but what if I want to use my code to find that?anyways all I was asking was just how to address items in list two time with duplicate items

Comment: @gonczor ah, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Remove duplicates in list (**Note** use this if order of elements is not important for you):

```
L = [1, 1, 3]
print(list(set(L)))
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 3]
```

Comment: `set` is unordered data type in python. This may not meet OP's requirements if they want to maintain order.

Comment: Yeah in that case, it's yours the right answer. +1 for you :)